# merge two javascript objects that contain arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, merge

I have the following...

```
array [
       obj1 = {key1: a,
               key2: [a, b, c]
               },

       obj2 = {key2: [c, d]}
];
```

And want the following outcome...

```
array[
       obj1 = {key1: a,
               key2: [a, b, c, d]
               }
]
```

How can I merge obj1 and obj2 so that key2 contains no duplicates?

Thanks!  I am also already using jQuery

Comment: Do you need a JSON object containing both arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var a = this.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }

    return a;
};   

var mergedArray = array1.concat(array2).unique();
```

via this question - [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript)